# Query posts: how to exclude results if post is in multiple categories

Tags: query-posts

Say I have 3 categories:  A, B, C, and another category D that posts in A,B,C can also be assigned to.  D is to denote the featured post for the category, and theoretically only one post for each (A, B, C) will also be assigned D.

I can find the featured post for each category fine using category__and .

I have a need to make a list of the rest of the category minus the featured post to the right of the featured post on the home page.  So for example I want to get a list of category A but I want to exclude the featured post that would be marked category A and category D.

I tried using "category_*in" followed by "category*_not_in" thinking it would accomplish this but the "category__not_in" seems to override and just find everything in every category except for the excluded category.

If I have things structured wrong please let me know.  I am trying to make things simple for the site owner by not having to remember to enter text for a tag (featured post).  I'd rather them just check the check boxes in the category list.

Summarizing, my code needs to do two things.  For example:

Find the "featured post": FIND A and D .  This is done.
Find everything in the category EXCEPT featured post:  Find A, exclude (A and D).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm new to Wordpress but not coding.  Just trying to get acquainted with the functionality.

Comment: As G.M. mentioned below, is there a reason you're not using sticky posts for your 'featured' items (instead of a separate category)? http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts

Comment: Don't use `query_posts`, there is no valid reason to use it when `WP_Query` and the `pre_get_posts` filter are available, or even `get_posts`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a "pure" way to do it, but this code make an array of featured post ids and then excludes them from future get_posts.

```
$featuredPosts = get_posts('category'=>'D','numberposts'=>'-1');
$fPId = array();
foreach ($featuredPost as $currentPost)
{
  array_push($fPId,$currentPost->ID);
}
$aPosts = get_posts('category' => 'a', 'exclude'=>$fpId);
$bPosts = get_posts('category' => 'b', 'exclude'=>$fpId);
$cPosts = get_posts('category' => 'c', 'exclude'=>$fpId);
```

Comment: Ah!  I didn't even think of taking that angle.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks!

Comment: @CraigCoston Fixed a syntax error

Comment: Wordpress as a core function [sticky posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts) that is intended for that purpose. Get only sticky posts: `'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )`, exclude stycky posts: `'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )` faster, simpler and most reliable on theme changing.